# Particle separate

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

I have created a blender animation with three particle systems, which use molecular script for collision. 
- 1st particle system are blue UV spheres, whithout magnetic field weight
- 2nd particle system are red UV spheres, whith magnetic field weight
- 3rd particle system are blue and red UV spheres, whith 0,5 magnetic field weight

[image]

Everything is working great, particles are moving along a plane, a magnetic field pulls the red UV spheres and mixed UV spheres on the upper plane, blue spheres are falling down, then mixed spheres fall down too in the middle of upper plane and the red spheres are  moving along on third plane. 
The process is magnetic separation animation.

The problem is, that the animation is not showing the exact process,... it should work something like this: 
There are 2 systems:
- 1st particle system are blue UV spheres, which should fall down 
- 2nd particle system are red UV spheres, which should go up by magnetic force
- 3rd particle system are red and blue spheres which are connected, but they SEPARATE half way on the upper plane, so that the blue spheres fall down.

Any suggestions? 
Thank you